# Issues compiling tikz with TeX Live 2016

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, texlive-2016

I have some issues with compiling this MWE code with *pdflatex* on Fedora 24, using TexLive 2016 that I installed from their website and DNF package. 
The same code works with the <s>latest</s> MiKTeX 2.9 installation on Windows 10.

These are the errors that I encountered.

```
Undefined control sequence. {x_{\ell-1} & x
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `$' or `$H' (in '{$H_{\ell -1}$}'). {x_{\ell-1} & x
```

And here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit, arrows, calc, positioning, patterns, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(MX)[matrix of math nodes, row sep=0pt, column sep=0pt,%
        %text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,%
        minimum width=\widthof{$H_{\ell-1}$},%
        minimum height=\heightof{$H_{\ell-1}$}]
        {x_{\ell-1} & x_{\ell-2} & \cdots & x_{1} & x_{0} \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome! If that compiles on MikTeX, you should complain!

Comment: @cfr: The code doesn't compile in a current miktex, but it does compile in texlive 2014 (despite that \widthof is undefined, probably the key is ignored). So it is also possible that it does compile in an older miktex.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I checked my pgf package and it was installed on 2014-09-19. Probably not updated unlike my fresh TeX Live

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED a bit thanks to  Torbjørn T. who discovered that earlier versions of PGF/Ti*k*Z probably allowed `\widthof` etc. here. See [Issues compiling tikz with TeX Live 2016](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328709/issues-compiling-tikz-with-tex-live-2016/328710?noredirect=1#comment805229_328710).

If that code compiles as is on MikTeX, your version of PGF/Ti*k*Z is probably outdated. Nothing you are loading defines either `\widthof` or `\heightof` and Ti*k*Z probably wouldn't like their use here anyway. Even if you load the `calc` package, Ti*k*Z doesn't like it (although you do get a different error in that case).

I'm not sure how things worked in earlier versions of PGF/Ti*k*Z, but `\widthof` etc. seem to have been defined to permit their use in this kind of case.

There are different ways of doing this e.g. `\pgfmathwidth` and `\pgfmathheight` are defined by standard TikZ. However, they cannot be used directly here in that form for the same reason the `calc` package's macros give an error.

The simplest solution is, therefore, to invoke them implicitly since this works fine and is designed to allow exactly this kind of thing.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(MX)[matrix of math nodes, row sep=0pt, column sep=0pt,
  minimum width=width("$H_{\ell-1}$"),
  minimum height=height("$H_{\ell-1}$")]
  {x_{\ell-1} & x_{\ell-2} & \cdots & x_{1} & x_{0} \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: simple]

Comment: Not being familiar with this stuff, I'm curious as to what was wrong with his initial code such that it was "screwy"? I noticed you eliminated a slew of libraries. Was there some clash there?

Comment: @Dennis Please see edit.

Comment: Actually, I think `\widthof` worked with `pgf` 2.10. Whether it loaded the `calc` package or defined its own version  I don't know, but I think that construct would have worked.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Loading the `calc` package doesn't help, though you do get a different error. Do you think PGF 2.10 defined it incompatibly and that's why it is not in 3? Or did 2.1 accept code at that point?

Comment: I had a grep at the 2.10 sources. `pgfmathparser.code.tex` has `\let\widthof=\pgfmath@calc@widthof` in line 44, and `\def\pgfmath@calc@widthof#1{width("#1")}` in line 95. So essentially just a wrapper  of `width()` it seems. Perhaps they removed it to avoid confusion with the `calc` package, I don't really know.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've edited the answer. It it a bit vague, but hopefully it diverges less dramatically from reality. Thanks very much for your comments. If you prefer to answer, I could edit mine to remove most of the explanation since most of my explanation was wrong anyway.

Comment: Nah, that's fine.